# javascript not calling in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I created a textbox and wrote `onfocus="getFocus()"`

Now I wrote function in javascript

```
function getFocus()

        {
            alert('Hello I Got Focus !!');
        }
```

The problem is in IE8 it worked perfectly, but in IE9 alert is not showing.
Can anyone tell what is wrong with the code ??

I also tried

```
txtAmt.Attributes.Add("onfocus","getFocus()")
```

but still it didn't worked

i too tried

```
txtAmt.Attributes.Add("onfocus","javascript:getFocus();")
```

Now i am worried.. what to do ??

Comment: change the attribute `onFocus` to lowercase: `onfocus`. For reasons that are still unclear to me, lowercase seems the way to go. There's nothing wrong with your code however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the IE developer tool (F12) after your page is loaded.

Check the Browser Mode: and Document Mode:

Try setting Browser Mode to IE9, and Document Mode to IE9 Standards.

Now try again and see if that works.

Comment: How is this the best answer? Just because you change your browser settings doesn't mean any of your visitors will. This is merely hiding the problem for yourself, not fixing it. :(

Comment: The question was what to do about the problem.  The first thing to do is determine if it really is a difference between IE8 and IE9, and this answer shows how to do that.  There are then a number of ways to fix the problem, if that really is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`onFocus` should be re-written as `onfocus = "getFocus()"`.

If it still doesn't work, then if IE9 is newly installed, you might want to check if Javascript is enabled in your installation of IE9. :)

Comment: actually when you are writing the stuff in the html of the textbox like <input type="textbox" focus="getFocus()">  .But if you are writing it in some script part like <script type="text/javascript"> input.onfocus="getFocus();" should be the syntax. Observe the omission of `on` word in the html part

Answer (score 2):

try javascript tag :

txtAmt.Attributes.Add("onfocus","javascript:getFocus();")

1. javascript doesn't fire if there is any error in page. Check for any error by enabling javascript debugging.
2. Some old versions of jquery is not supported in ie9 (version below 1.4.1)

Comment: There is no error on the page, it worked fine in IE8. Then why this is happening in IE9..

Comment: what version of jquery is referred in your project ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, have you tried checking the security settings of IE?

if you go

```
 Internet Options > Security > Custom level > 

 Make sure Active Scripting is not set to Disabled
```